# Is there a way to change the Windows default color picker?

Tags: windows-7, colors

I have to keep entering custom colors by hand and its a pain! There has to be a better way to do this -- especially on applications that are using the default color picker...

Anyone?

From any third party text or image editor -- they always use the default Windows color picker -- is there a way to use better version of this for setting colors --

Comment: Maybe if you better defined the process with which you are using the color picker, someone might be able to suggest something. But just to replace the color picker altogether, I don't see a way to replace that particular control (though I could be wrong).

Comment: Note that – at least I assume so – this question was closed for asking for product recommendations. The answers are all just links to third party color pickers.

Answer (score 4):

Try [PasteColor](http://pastecolor.rolandtoth.hu/). I made it exactly for the same purpose. PasteColor is a Windows color picker helper tool that helps you copy or paste color values with ease.

Comment: Read [this post](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225), you must.  Also be careful about promoting your own products.  It's fine once in a while, just make sure that you don't spam other questions with your product(s).  Oh and welcome to Super User! :)

Answer (score 1):

I used [Jovian](http://www.joviancolorpicker.com/) briefly for the ten free color selections it allows you in the trial.  I installed it while Eclipse was up and running, because it was a pain trying to copy hex color codes from a web page into the Windows color picker that only takes RGB values.  Once Jovian was installed, I didn't have to restart Eclipse or anything, I just hit a button to select a color in Eclipse like usual, and the Windows color picker showed up for a second before suddenly disappearing and the Jovian picker was there instead--so I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I like [Iconico's ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/). Its free and works on all versions of windows.
The UI is slightly awkward. You have to alt-G (for grab) to toggle capture, move to that pixel and (alt-G) to finalize the capture. Once a color is captured